# Converting numeric fields into strings with leading zeros

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, string, leading-zero

I'm trying to define an action in QGIS using on of my fields but I have some problems with its format.

I have a numeric string like '5' and I need to have a format like '005'. I've tried function `tostring("myfield")` but I am not able to define the format that I want.stri

Is there any way to do something like `tostring(myfield,"000")`?

What I'm looking for is a function like this one: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-HP005209313.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005204211

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is:

```
'000'   ||  tostring("myfield")
```

(a variable = 'variable') + (string concatenation  = ||) +  (field = "myfield")

5 -> 0005
50 -> 00050
500 -> 000500

combining variables

```
'hello'   || ', ' ||  tostring("myfield")
```

5 -> hello, 5

```
'hello'   || ', ' ||  tostring("myfield") || ', goodbye'
```

5 -> hello, 5, goodbye

combining fields

```
tostring("myfield") || ', ' || tostring("otherfield")
```

combining other thinks, like geometry

For example, for a point, the x and y coordinates -> (x, y)

```
'('   ||   $x  ||   ','   ||  $y  || ' )'
```

and you can format the result

```
right(  ('000'   ||  tostring(  "myfield" )), 4)
```

5 -> 0005
50 -> 0050
500 -> 0500

etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've tried your last option but there was a problem because there isn't "right" function in QGIS 1.8. I've used "substr" and "length" function like this: 
substr( ( '000' || tostring ("myfield")) , ( length ( ( '000' || tostring("myfield")) ) -2) , 3 )
Then I've obtained '005'. 
Thanks again.

Comment: Great response and thanks for posting all these alternative formatting patterns. Massively useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Another, and possibly more compact, option using [`lpad()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#lpad) (Left Pad) under String Functions which requires three arguments: *the field, desired length, and padding character*

```
lpad("MyField", 3, '0')
```

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS 1.8 I've used this one because there wasn't `right()` function:

```
substr(('000' || tostring("myfield")), (length(('000' || tostring("myfield")))-2), 3)
```

And I've obtained 005