# Modifying Fields in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, actions

I'm pretty new to Quantum GIS, and I was looking to add zeros to a field I was having some trouble with.  I learned through browsing a few posts here that existing fields can be modified by defining actions.  My question is, how does this process work?  How do I go about defining actions and what is the language (for example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62168/how-to-convert-numeric-fields-into-strings-with-leading-zeros)) used to define these actions?

Example: `substr( ( '000' || tostring ("myfield")) , ( length ( ( '000' || tostring("myfield")) ) -2) , 3 )`

Comment: I'm unclear on what you wnat to do - modify a field data type, or just change values *in* the field? I suspect that what you're looking for is the [Field Calculator](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html?highlight=field%20calculator) tool and the available functions/syntax can be found on that help page. You appear to be mixing two things up - defining actions is separate from changing a field value. Your linked question is trying to define an action, but that action expects/needs a certain input format which the field doesn't currently have.

Comment: As a generality fields can't be modified; if it's an int it will always be an int, if it's a string field with a length of 50 it will always be a string field with a length of 50. You can change the values that the field stores as Chris said or the display of the field within QGIS but the underlying field remains the same. Padding 0's has **absolutely no effect on numeric type fields** and only affects string fields. Some data types, specifically database data types, allow for changing fields using the underlying database program (eg. PostGIS using PostgreSQL) but most don't.

Comment: @ChrisW Thanks, I think that's what I was looking for.  What do you mean by "which the field doesn't currently have"?  Which field?  The one referenced in the linked question?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thanks.  It sounds like what you're saying is that in my example my field would have to be some string datatype for the function I posted to work.  It wouldn't be possible to export this as a CSV and then change it back to a number in something like Excel?

Comment: Yes, but the trick is getting it back should you need to. You cannot modify the dbf file with shapefiles in Excel, it will break them if you save, but you can save as Excel. When the data is imported into Excel with padded leading 0's it will be recognized as a text field but changing the type (format) in Excel will convert it to a number easily.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the linked question. Define an [action](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html) (scroll down) is what that asker was trying to do, but their problem was their field values - the input *to* the action. The action itself isn't what changes the field value. It would be helpful if you tell us exactly what you have and are trying to do, and what is giving you trouble. You can *display* leading zeros without changing a value if it's numeric, but you cannot *store* them unless it's a string as @MichaelMiles-Stimson says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is the [Field Calculator](http://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html?highlight=field%20calculator), and the available functions/syntax can be found on that help page.

In the question you link to, [Defining an Action](http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html) (scroll about halfway down the page) is a separate thing from modifying the field values - not the way to do so. The asker at the other question is trying to define an action. That action expects the field values to be in a certain format (005) and they aren't (5).

If you can add additional information about what/how you are wanting to "add zeros to a field", we may be able to provide more specific help. As Michael Miles-Stimson explains in the comments, you can [*display*](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000003s000000) leading zeros without changing a value if a field data type is numeric, but you cannot *store* leading zeros unless the datatype is string. And then there's conversion work back and forth between string and numeric if/when you want to perform math on those values.

---

This is also true in Excel - when it comes to actual numbers, leading zeros don't *mean* anything - they're for display purposes only. The example in your question is about altering the characters of a string - they just happen to be numeral characters.

Displayed value is just that - formatting basically. Again, we're talking about numeric data types here. The actual stored value may vary considerably and is based on data type. A `double` stores more digits than an `int`, but both *could* be displayed the same way.

Leading zeros are never actually stored because they provide no meaning. Better to take that available space for more decimal precision because trailing zeros **do** always mean something. You can make software show you leading zeros, but it tacks them on to the beginning of the stored value - which might go out to twelve decimal places but only display six.

Functions depend on the data type - you can't run a string function on numeric data. And yes, a function operates on the actual value regardless of what is displayed. This can actually be a significant issue.

9 x 5.2345364213645634 is different than 9 x 5.2345360000000000, but if you're only displaying six decimal places you may not see it.

Comment: Thanks Chris, would you be able to elaborate on what you mean by display vs store?  I assume that very few functions work with displayed values, just as actions fail.

Comment: @114 Done. Hopefully that covers it, let me know if not.